# Return multiple results from VLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet (example here: [Demo Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10wbbeCYdkyKfu0PetIXqs1fhm4rjJ5PIyIjpf3yNRoU/edit?usp=sharing))

Sheet 1: contains a list of users with their email address and name.
Sheet 2: contains a list of and the groups that they are a member of.
Sheet 3: I want to 'flip' sheet 2, so rather than have the user and each group, I want the group with each member listed.

I have tried `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet2!A2:A11,Sheet2!B2:E11=A2))`
But Filters need to be a single column, I tried to flatten and get the unique values and use that but it came back with a mismatched quantity.

Anyone have any clue how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it:

```
=index(split(trim(transpose(query(if(regexmatch(
substitute(substitute(trim(transpose(query(transpose(
substitute(Sheet2!B2:E," ","❄️")),,9^9)))," ",","),"❄️"," "),
transpose(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>""))),Sheet2!A2:A,),,9^9)))," "))
```

[image]